# Awaited store for Svelte

Tags: typescript, reactive-programming, svelte

In my [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) app, I need to reactively fetch data from the server and then render the result. The ideal data struture for this is a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) whose values are promises – eg. like this:

```js
let article = writable("about");
let text = derived(article, a => fetch(`http://example.com?article=${a}`));
```

However, the way I want to render the values is different from this representation: if the `article` variable changes, I still want to render the previous text and overlay it with a spinner until the new text loads (ie. until the promise resolves). Because something like this could be useful in more places, I decided to write a little helper function for this.

The `awaitedStore` function takes a store whose values are promises, and returns two new stores: `lastValue` and `settled`. The `lastValue` store contains the last resolved value – if the original store changes to a new promise, `lastValue` won't update until the promise is resolved. The `resolved` store contains a boolean indicating whether the current promise is settled or not – the UI can display a spinner any time `resolved` is false.

There are a few other important features:

- if neither `lastValue` nor `resolved` have a subscriber, then we don't subscribe to the original store
- never update `lastValue` with an outdated promise – if a new promise comes before the old was resolved, we stop waiting until it resolves

This is the code:

```js
import { writable, type Readable } from "svelte/store"

function cancellableThen<T>(p: Promise<T>, f: (v: T) => void): () => void {
  let canceled = false;
  p.then((v) => {
    if (canceled) return;
    f(v);
  });
  return () => (canceled = true);
}

const Void: void = void 0;

export function awaitedStore<T>(store: Readable<Promise<T>>): {
  lastValue: Readable<T | undefined>;
  resolved: Readable<boolean>;
} {
  let cold = true;
  let lastValueHasSubscriber = false;
  let loadingHasSubscriber = false;

  const start = (what: "lastValue" | "loading") => () => {
    if (what === "lastValue") lastValueHasSubscriber = true;
    if (what === "loading") loadingHasSubscriber = true;

    const stop = () => {
      if (what === "lastValue") lastValueHasSubscriber = false;
      if (what === "loading") loadingHasSubscriber = false;
      if (lastValueHasSubscriber || loadingHasSubscriber) return;

      cold = true;
      unsubPromise?.();
      unsubStore();
    };

    if (!cold) return stop;
    cold = false;

    let unsubPromise = () => Void;
    const unsubStore = store.subscribe((p) => {
      unsubPromise?.();
      resolved.set(false);
      unsubPromise = cancellableThen(p, (v) => {
        lastValue.set(v);
        resolved.set(true);
      });
    });

    return stop;
  };

  const lastValue = writable<T | undefined>(undefined, start("lastValue"));
  const resolved = writable(false, start("loading"));

  return { lastValue, resolved };
}
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgdysGBDARgGwKYA0cMAnmHnAEp4YAm2+cAvnAGZQQhwBEAzgG54cMPAHpeMaHm4BuAFBzWAVwB2AYxjAIKuGozqhOBngAqACzwqAPCYB8ACjAAuOAAUOIYLzw3bRVi72-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-RgYsE6vpRh4vpBqICohyEePCU7LKc8R0WOOFIVg+GDFcYKDJUAl9uq9RgImc4IbhWAofCGGESeAy0vSjLiUM9j2t4Oxqaxinsd4VyrDgRh4uYliOEQDQznyakfkW2kwFMcmtIMdIMn0rn2EOBknjMr7BUx6kLDotEtMRkEukczlbFcqDoNCJgRiSZIUlS9gZeSlK0EQ7qwPYq6FhugVxfAXmaX0SVoJgeK6UehWYMVLbRrGoQ7C01E6EgCWEOp3mMsw8h7EAA). [Link to Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/508468f73f2644a6aa0aa04d042a1226?version=3.52.0).

An obvious shortcoming of the code is the lack of error handling – I decided to omit it in favor of simplicity, and I intend to add it later.

Comment: For starters, how about using an [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) for the cancellablePromise?

Comment: AbortController is cool but it's only supported by fetch. There are many other Promise usecases that don't involve fetch. Furthermore, AbortController would lead to unwanted behavior unless `awaitedStore` is the sole consumer of those promises. Eg. if there were two components that use the same fetched data in different ways, one of them could cancel a request that is awaited by the other one. My code makes no such assumptions. To sum up: while I agree that, in this specific usecase, AbortController would make the code more optimized, it would also be less general and would introduce a footgun

Comment: Can you explain why you need this part: if neither `lastValue` nor `resolved` have a subscriber, then we don't subscribe to the original store. I don't understand why you need this

Answer (score 2):

Your `awaitedStore` function is rather verbose. All of the functionality for unsubscribing and resubscribing to the input store seems unnecessary. I also noticed that since the `cancellableThen` function is only used once and never exported, it made sense just to inline the functionality.

Here is a shorter implementation of `awaitedStore`:

```typescript
// awaited-store.ts
import { writable, type Readable } from "svelte/store"

export function awaited<T>(store: Readable<Promise<T>>): {
  loading: Readable<boolean>;
  value: Readable<T>;
} {
  const value = writable<T>();
  const loading = writable<boolean>(true);

  store.subscribe((promise) => {
    loading.set(true);
    const valueThen = get(value);
    promise.then((result) => {
      const valueNow = get(value);
      if (valueThen !== valueNow) return;
      value.set(result);
      loading.set(false);
    });
  });

  return { loading, value };
}
```

And it is used the same way, I just renamed `settled` to `loading` and `lastValue` to `value` because those names seemed more obvious to me as to what the variable represented.

```svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import { writable, derived } from "svelte/store";
  import { awaited } from "./awaited-store.ts";
  import { fetchPost } from "./utils.ts";

  const postId = writable(1);
  const article = derived(postId, (id) => fetchPost(id));
  const { loading, value } = awaited(article);
</script>

{#if $loading}
  <p>Loading...</p>
{/if}
{#if $value}
  <article>
    <h2>{$value.title}</h2>
    <p>{$value.body}</p>
  </article>
{/if}
```

[Demo link on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yv49zp?file=src%2FApp.svelte,src%2Flib%2Fawaited-store.ts)

Let me know if there are any issues; I haven't tested this thoroughly yet.